# Best Practices to enable CI/CD in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was wondering if creating multiple  Business Units in Salesforce Marketing Cloud for testing and sprint development aside from one for PROD was a typical and facile way to set up the Marketing Cloud deployment process?

Is there a way to avoid manually recreating everything in the next Business Unit for each deployment sprint? How else can we implement some semblance of continuous integration in SFMC? Thoughts, Ideas appreciated...

Is there a sandbox coming in any forseeable release of SFMC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should look at package manager

Comment: in conjunction with the [deployment manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5) if the package manager errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my opinion, but I wouldn't even bother with setting up a sandbox business unit.

It's better to consider SFMC as "all production".  Development and QA configuration is most efficient as simple copies with different names in the same BU.

Package Manager and Deployment Manager are hamstrung by limitations of the web services.  There are too many dependencies to be satisfied to move configurations.  They'll never be stable or complete enough to mirror a CI/CD process.

Comment: I would upvote this a million times if I could, but alas I can only give one.